# Windows 7 won't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, window

I need a little help, my laptop will no boot into Windows
I am running Toshiba L300-1AS (Native to Vista)
It is currently running Windows 7 HP which was running fine for months.
It was slowing down and I could not find the issue so I wiped and re-installed the OS. This was about 6 Weeks ago.
This morning I shut my laptop off and when I got home and turned it on it wouldn't boot.

Windows 7 starts the boot process the bootscreen comes up (The windows logo saying starting windows) This just hangs and my hard drive light blinks like crazy. I have to shut down Via Power Button.

I tried to boot into safe mode via F8 and when loading the files it gets so far through and just hangs, hard drive light flashing.

I tried to boot via my Windows 7 System Disc (downloaded from the internet) The one with just the repair files from the install disc. Startup repair, cmd etc. That loads the files and when the green loading bar comes up the computer hangs power light flashing.

I have run memtest and there is nothing wrong with my RAM
I managed to boot the computer to Linux and backup my files in case i need to format but I would rather avoid that if at all possible.

Please if you need more details just ask.

Edit: Turned on laptop, went to do stuff, came back laptop booted? Weird much I think time for a check disk anything else anyone can recommend i do now I'm in windows.

Comment: Sounds like you should perform a malware scan and/or check the health of you hdd.

Comment: I have an old copy of hirens that i've used on other computers to stress test the hard drive and other components, if they are close to going the program kills the component, but I can't even get it to boot that.

Just to add I'm sure when I shut the computer off it installed updates.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your hard drive is dying. I would suggest spending some time looking into [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) and other utilities included in the excellent [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).

If those don't work, you might want to try some more heavy-duty utilities, say [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) (I've been listening to Security Now a bit too much, I realize now), or [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/s/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) (here's a nice [HOWTO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=308821)).

Congrats on knowing to backup--it's a habit that'll last you a lifetime :-).

Comment: fun fun, i have backups always theres never anything truly essential on my system. Out of those listed which would you suggest as best to see if my hard drive is dying?

Comment: Spinrite, but it's $90. Second would be ddrescue, but that has a learning curve.

Comment: Fact of the matter is for $90 i could get a new hard drive its just not worth the outlay, the only reason im trying to fix it is because I cant afford a new hard drive at the moment

Answer (score 0):

When trying to boot using f8 in safe mode, where does it freeze? Does it say which library it is loading?

It doesn't sound like a MBR problem - but like a corrupt system file. If you have backed up your files, you may want to consider reformatting and reinstalling. Then you can load your files into the fresh install - and do a backup disk image.

Comment: The file that doesn't load is \windows\system32\DRIVERS\CLASSPNP.SYS now i've seen this i will have a look on google, I thought it was irrelevant considering my other issues.

Comment: That could very well be the offender - but often I have found that when one file is corrupted, so are others. My preferred course of action is to restore a backup - or reformat->reinstall->backup if losing files isn't an issue.